# BEA : Migration of live workflow instances

Tags: oracle, workflow, weblogic, weblogic8.x, bea

I want to migrate database server from Oracle 9i to Oracle 11g (WebLogic version is 8.1 SP5).
After migration, WebLogic version will remain the same. Only database gets changed.

How can I achieve this?

Is taking DB dump before migration and importing dump after migration enough for this task?

Or do I need to do other things as well?

Thanks.

Comment: So, you will keep your app server as-is and will upgrade your database server version? Do they reside on the same machine or in different machines?

Comment: Application server and DB Server are on different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most likely a DB dump will do the trick. Oracle data types are backward compatible, so, you are covered.